# After Uprading from SLES 12 to SLES 15, DNS resolution Doesn't Work

Tags: sles

My /etc/resolv.conf:

```
### /etc/resolv.conf file autogenerated by netconfig!
#
# Before you change this file manually, consider to define the
# static DNS configuration using the following variables in the
# /etc/sysconfig/network/config file:
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SEARCHLIST
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_FORWARDER
# or disable DNS configuration updates via netconfig by setting:
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY=''
#
# See also the netconfig(8) manual page and other documentation.
#
# Note: Manual change of this file disables netconfig too, but
# may get lost when this file contains comments or empty lines
# only, the netconfig settings are same with settings in this
# file and in case of a "netconfig update -f" call.
#
### Please remove (at least) this line when you modify the file!
```

I checked the value of NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS in /etc/sysconfig/network/config and that is correct.

In yast lan, Hostname/DNS, Modify DNS Configuration, it says "Only Manually" and the DNS servers are listed under "Name Servers and Domain Search List"
Here is my /etc/sysconfig/network/config:

```
## Type:        yesno
## Default:     yes
# sometimes we want some script to be executed after an interface has been
# brought up, or before an interface is taken down.
# default dir is /etc/sysconfig/network/if-up.d for POST_UP and
# /etc/sysconfig/network/if-down.d for PRE_DOWN
# Note: if you use NetworkManager then down scripts will be called after the
# interface is down and not before.
GLOBAL_POST_UP_EXEC="yes"
GLOBAL_PRE_DOWN_EXEC="yes"
## Path:        Network/General
## Description: Global network configuration
## Type:        yesno
## Default:     no
# If ifup should check if an ip address is already in use, set this to yes.
# Make sure that packet sockets (CONFIG_PACKET) are supported in the kernel,
# since this feature uses arping, which depends on that.
# Also be aware that this takes one second per interface; consider that when
# setting up a lot of interfaces.
CHECK_DUPLICATE_IP="no"

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     no
# Switch on/off debug messages for all network configuration stuff. If set to no
# most scripts can enable it locally with "-o debug".
DEBUG="no"

# Handling of network connections
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# These features are designed for the convenience of the experienced
# user. If you encounter problems you don't understand then switch
# them off. That is the default.
# Please do not complain if you get troubles. But if you want help to
# make them smarter write to <http://www.suse.de/feedback>.

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     no
#
# If you are interested in the connections and nfs mounts that use a
# network interface, you can set CONNECTION_SHOW_WHEN_IFSTATUS="yes".
# Then you will see them with 'ifstatus <interface>' (or 'ifstatus
# <config>')
# This one _should_ never harm ;)
#
CONNECTION_SHOW_WHEN_IFSTATUS="no"

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     no
#
# If an interface should be set down only if there are no active
# connections, then use CONNECTION_CHECK_BEFORE_IFDOWN="yes"
#
CONNECTION_CHECK_BEFORE_IFDOWN="no"

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     no
#
# If these connetions (without the nfs mounts) should be closed when
# shutting down an interface, set CONNECTION_CLOSE_BEFORE_IFDOWN="yes".
# WARNING: Be aware that this may terminate applications which need
# one of these connections!
#
CONNECTION_CLOSE_BEFORE_IFDOWN="no"

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     no
#
# If you are a mobile laptop user and like even nfs mounts to be
# closed when you leave your current workplace, then set
# CONNECTION_UMOUNT_NFS_BEFORE_IFDOWN="yes". This does only work
# if CONNECTION_CLOSE_BEFORE_IFDOWN="yes", too.
# WARNING: Be aware that this may terminate applications which use
# these nfs mounts as working directory. Be very carefull if your home
# is mounted via nfs!!!
# WARNING: This may even lead to hanging ifdown processes if there are
# processes that could not be terminated. If you are using
# hotpluggable devices (pcmcia, usb, firewire), first shut them down
# before unplugging!
#
CONNECTION_UMOUNT_NFS_BEFORE_IFDOWN="no"

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     no
#
# If terminating processes that use a connection or nfs mount is not
# enough, then they can be killed after an unsuccesfull termination.
# If you want that set CONNECTION_SEND_KILL_SIGNAL="yes"
#
CONNECTION_SEND_KILL_SIGNAL="no"

## Type:        integer
## Default:     30
#
# Some interfaces need some time to come up or come asynchronously via hotplug.
# WAIT_FOR_INTERFACES is a global wait for all mandatory interfaces in
# seconds. If empty no wait occurs.
#
WAIT_FOR_INTERFACES="30"

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     yes
#
# With this variable you can determine if the SuSEfirewall when enabled
# should get started when network interfaces are started.
FIREWALL="yes"

## Type:        int
## Default:     30
#
# When using NetworkManager you may define a timeout to wait for NetworkManager
# to connect in /etc/init.d/network(-remotefs) script.  Other network services
# may require the system to have a valid network setup in order to succeed.
#
# This variable has no effect if NETWORKMANAGER=no.
#
NM_ONLINE_TIMEOUT="30"

## Type:        string
## Default:     "dns-resolver dns-bind ntp-runtime nis"
#
# This variable defines the start order of netconfig modules installed
# in the /etc/netconfig.d/ directory.
#
# To disable the execution of a module, don't remove it from the list
# but prepend it with a minus sign, "-ntp-runtime".
#
NETCONFIG_MODULES_ORDER="dns-resolver dns-bind dns-dnsmasq nis ntp-runtime"

## Type:        string
## Default:     "auto"
#
# Defines the DNS merge policy as documented in netconfig(8) manual page.
# Set to "" to disable DNS configuration.
#
NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY=""

## Type:        string(resolver,bind,dnsmasq,)
## Default:     "resolver"
#
# Defines the name of the DNS forwarder that has to be configured.
# Currently implemented are "bind", "dnsmasq" and "resolver", that
# causes to write the name server IP addresses to /etc/resolv.conf
# only (no forwarder). Empty string defaults to "resolver".
#
NETCONFIG_DNS_FORWARDER="resolver"

## Type:        string
## Default:     ""
#
# List of DNS domain names used for host-name lookup.
# It is written as search list into the /etc/resolv.conf file.
#
NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SEARCHLIST="test.com"

## Type:        string
## Default:     ""
#
# List of DNS nameserver IP addresses to use for host-name lookup.
# When the NETCONFIG_DNS_FORWARDER variable is set to "resolver",
# the name servers are written directly to /etc/resolv.conf.
# Otherwise, the nameserver are written into a forwarder specific
# configuration file and the /etc/resolv.conf does not contain any
# nameservers causing the glibc to use the name server on the local
# machine (the forwarder). See also netconfig(8) manual page.
#
NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS="172.19.9.12 172.19.9.13 172.19.9.14"

## Type:        string
## Default:     "auto"
#
# Allows to specify a custom DNS service ranking list, that is which
# services provide preferred (e.g. vpn services), and which services
# fallback settings (e.g. avahi).
# Preferred service names have to be prepended with a "+", fallback
# service names with a "-" character. The special default value
# "auto" enables the current build-in service ranking list -- see the
# netconfig(8) manual page -- "none" or "" disables the ranking.
#
NETCONFIG_DNS_RANKING="auto"

## Type:        string
## Default:     "auto"
#
# Defines the NTP merge policy as documented in netconfig(8) manual page.
# Set to "" to disable NTP configuration.
#
NETCONFIG_NTP_POLICY="auto"

## Type:        string
## Default:     ""
#
# List of NTP servers.
#
NETCONFIG_NTP_STATIC_SERVERS=""

## Type:        string
## Default:     "auto"
#
# Defines the NIS merge policy as documented in netconfig(8) manual page.
# Set to "" to disable NIS configuration.
#
NETCONFIG_NIS_POLICY="auto"

## Type:        string(yes,no,)
## Default:     "yes"
#
# Defines whether to set the default NIS domain. When enabled and no domain
# is provided dynamically or in static settings, /etc/defaultdomain is used.
# Valid values are:
#  - "no" or ""         netconfig does not set the domainname
#  - "yes"              netconfig sets the domainname according to the
#                       NIS policy using settings provided by the first
#                       iterface and service that provided it.
#  - "<interface name>" as yes, but only using settings from interface.
#
NETCONFIG_NIS_SETDOMAINNAME="yes"

## Type:        string
## Default:     ""
#
# Defines a default NIS domain.
#
# Further domain can be specified by adding a "_<number>" suffix to
# the NETCONFIG_NIS_STATIC_DOMAIN and NETCONFIG_NIS_STATIC_SERVERS
# variables, e.g.: NETCONFIG_NIS_STATIC_DOMAIN_1="second".
#
NETCONFIG_NIS_STATIC_DOMAIN=""

## Type:        string
## Default:     ""
#
# Defines a list of NIS servers for the default NIS domain or the
# domain specified with same "_<number>" suffix.
#
NETCONFIG_NIS_STATIC_SERVERS=""

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     yes
#
# When enabled (default) in forwarder mode ("bind", "dnsmasq"),
# netconfig writes an explicit localhost nameserver address to the
# /etc/resolv.conf, followed by the policy resolved name server list
# as fallback for the moments, when the local forwarder is stopped.
#
NETCONFIG_DNS_FORWARDER_FALLBACK="yes"

## Type:        list(auto,yes,no)
## Default:     auto
# If ifup should send a gratuitous ARP to inform the receivers about its
# static IP addresses and perhaps also a link-layer (MAC) address change.
# Make sure that packet sockets (CONFIG_PACKET) are supported in the kernel,
# since this feature uses arping, which depends on that.
SEND_GRATUITOUS_ARP="no"

## Type:        integer
## Default:     0
#
# The number of seconds to wait for link to become useable / ready.
# Default is 0, causing to not wait for a ready link (0), because link
# detection can't be enabled in all cases (e.g. bridges without ports).
# Please use per interface settings to enable it.
#
LINK_READY_WAIT="0"

## Type:        integer
## Default:     ""
#
# The number of seconds to wait for the end of IPv6 duplicate address
# detection in ifup.
# Default is to use WAIT_FOR_INTERFACES/2 seconds in normal ifup runs.
# When ifup is called by /etc/init.d/network at boot time, the check
# is done, but /etc/init.d/network waits WAIT_FOR_INTERFACES seconds
# for all interfaces togerther. Set to 0 to disable it.
#
IPV6_DAD_WAIT=""

## Type:        string
## Default:     ''
#
# Set this variable global variable to the ISO / IEC 3166 alpha2
# country code specifying the wireless regulatory domain to set.
# When not empty, ifup-wireless will be set in the wpa_supplicant
# config or via 'iw reg set' command.
#
# Note: This option requires a wpa driver supporting it, like
# the 'nl80211' driver used by default since openSUSE 11.3.
# When you notice problems with your hardware, please file a
# bug report and set e.g. WIRELESS_WPA_DRIVER='wext' (the old
# default driver) in the ifcfg file.
# See also "/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant --help" for the list of
# available wpa drivers.
#
WIRELESS_REGULATORY_DOMAIN=''

## Type:        string
## Default:     ""
#
# Allows to specify a comma separated list of debug facilities used
# by wicked. Negated facility names can be prepended by a "-", e.g.:
#   "all,-events,-socket,-objectmodel,xpath,xml,dbus"
#
# When set, wicked debug level is automatically enabled.
# For a complete list of facility names, see: "wicked --debug help".
#
WICKED_DEBUG=""

## Type:        list("",error,warning,notice,info,debug,debug1,debug2,debug3)
## Default:     ""
#
# Allows to specify wicked debug level. Default level is "notice".
#
WICKED_LOG_LEVEL=""

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     no
#
# Enable netconfig verbose reporting.
#
NETCONFIG_VERBOSE="no"

## Type:        yesno
## Default:     no
#
# This variable enables netconfig to always force a replace of modified
# files and automatically enables the -f | --force-replace parameter.
#
# The purpose is to use it as workaround, when some other tool trashes
# the files, e.g. /etc/resolv.conf and you observe messages like this
# in your logs on in "netconfig update" output:
# ATTENTION: You have modified /etc/resolv.conf. Leaving it untouched.
#
# Please do not forget to also report a bug as we have a system policy
# to use netconfig.
#
NETCONFIG_FORCE_REPLACE="no"

## Type:        string
## Default:     ""
#
# Allows to specify options to use when writting the /etc/resolv.conf,
# for example:
#       "debug attempts:1 timeout:10"
# See resolv.conf(5) manual page for details.
#
NETCONFIG_DNS_RESOLVER_OPTIONS=""

## Type:        string
## Default:     ""
#
# Allows to specify a sortlist to use when writting the /etc/resolv.conf,
# for example:
#       130.155.160.0/255.255.240.0 130.155.0.0"
# See resolv.conf(5) manual page for details.
#
NETCONFIG_DNS_RESOLVER_SORTLIST=""
## Type:        integer
## Default:     ""
#
# How log to wait for IPv6 autoconfig in ifup when requested with
# the auto6 or +auto6 tag in BOOTPROTO variable.
# When unset, a wicked built-in default defer time (10sec) is used.
#
AUTO6_WAIT_AT_BOOT=""

## Type:        list(all,dns,none,"")
## Default:     ""
#
# Whether to update system (DNS) settings from IPv6 RA when requested
# with the auto6 or +auto6 tag in BOOTPROTO variable.
# Defaults to update if autoconf sysctl (address autoconf) is enabled.
#
AUTO6_UPDATE=""

## Type:        list(auto,yes,no)
## Default:     "auto"
#
# Permits to specify/modify a global ifcfg default. Use with care!
#
# This settings breaks rules for many things, which require carrier
# before they can start, e.g. L2 link protocols, link authentication,
# ipv4 duplicate address detection, ipv6 duplicate detection will
# happen "post-mortem" and maybe even cause to disable ipv6 at all.
# See also "man ifcfg" for further informations.
#
LINK_REQUIRED="auto"
```

Comment: please post /etc/sysconfig/network/config. also try to fix dns resolution using yast.

Comment: ok. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY` is set to a blank string, which is explicitly telling `netconfig` not to mess with your `resolv.conf` which is otherwise empty. You need to read the `netconfig(8)` manpage to determine what policy you want it to use. Alternatively, add the line:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

to the bottom of `resolv.conf` until you figure out what you want `netconfig` to do.